# firestoreConnect or Firestore returns "undefined" when including where query parameter

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

The firebaseConnect HOC returns undefined for 'collections'.  However, if I remove the 'where' parameters, it returns data.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    contestants: state.firestore.ordered['ContestantsList-contestants'],
    votes: state.firestore.ordered['ContestantsList-votes'],
    currentUserId: state.firebase.auth.uid,
  }
}

export default compose(
  firestoreConnect(ownProps => {
    // added this console log to verify that ownProps.contestId exists.
    console.log('ownProps', {...ownProps})
    return ([
      {
        collection: 'votes',
        where: [
          ['authorId', '==', ownProps.currentUserId],
          ['contestId', '==', ownProps.contestId],
        ],
        storeAs: 'ContestantsList-votes'
      },
      {
        collection: 'contestants',
        orderBy: ['createdAt', 'asc'],
        where: ['contestId', '==', ownProps.contestId],  // <---- If I remove this line, it works
        storeAs: 'ContestantsList-contestants',
      },
    ])
  }),
  connect(mapStateToProps),
)(ContestantsList);
```

In the above code, the `votes` prop is an array of data, as expected.  The `contestants` prop comes back as undefined.  I have absolutely no idea why this would happen.  I'm hoping it's really obvious to an experienced Firestore user.  I'm new to Firebase and Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

I did solve the problem.  It was a race condition.  I created an HOC that contained this query, and wrapped several components with the HOC.  The intent was to make the components as modular as possible and avoid passing data through components to other components.

My approach meant the query ran several times as components were rendered.  It updated redux state several times in rapid succession.  A race condition ensued.

I had to reorganize my project so that the query was only made once, and then updated my HOC's to read the results directly from redux.  So, it was my problem in the end.